# Django ORM - Savings with **kwargs and retrieving instance

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Currently saving to my Product model like so:

```
Product(**kwargs).save()
```

How can I retrieve the instance immediately without performing a query similar to below?

```
Product.objects.get(unique_val = kwargs['unique_val'])
```

Thanks

EDIT: I'm trying to avoid hitting the database a much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`.create(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#create) of the model manager:

```
my_product = Product.objects.create(**kwargs)
```

or you can simply do it with a two-liner:

```
my_product = Product(**kwargs)
my_product.save()
```

There exist variants of the `.create(..)` method like [**`get_or_create(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) and [**`update_or_create(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create).